# get name of the last command in a script

Tags: linux, bash

How do I get the name of the last command that was run in a script ?

For example :

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo error, this command returned a non-zero status: $NAME_OF_THE_COMMAND', ERR

echo 'hey I\'m the first command !'
cat somefile #here it will return a non-zero number
...
```

I know I could use $? for the pid. But since I am a child I have always wanted to access the name instead of the pid. I tried 'echo $BASH_COMMAND' ( not in a trap ) but it just echoes 'echo $BASH_COMMAND'.

Any idea ?

Comment: `$?` is the exit code of the last command, not the PID.

Comment: oops indeed I should reread my posts before posting, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
trap 'echo "Error, $BASH_COMMAND returned with status $?"' ERR
```

Comment: One problem with `$BASH_COMMAND` won't have variables evaluated.  e.g. `$bad_command` will echo as `Error, $bad_command -- returned 1` .
To see `$bad_command` evaluated, try this modified trap statement (uses `eval`)
**`trap 'eval echo "Error, ${BASH_COMMAND} -- returned $?"' ERR`**
Now, you will see message `Error, cp badfile somewhere -- returned 1`